# Blueprint For Switching Between Cameras In The Unreal Engine

Tags: camera, scripting, unreal-4, unreal

So basically I have a scene in the Unreal Engine which has multiple cameras within it, the cameras are intentionally static as the application should behave more like a viewing gallery than a game. As the application is intended for mobile devices, the idea is that when a person touches the screen of their device, the rendering switches from the present camera to another one to show a different image. I have attempted to implement this action in the level blueprint with the following blueprint design:

[image]

Closer up:

[image]

Obviously in the scene there are three camera actors which must be switched between with the first camera viewed through being the 1st CameraActor hence the connection of the EventBeginPlay variable to the Set View Target With Blend variable that the 1st camera actor is connected to. When the Play button is pressed, the scene viewed from the first camera is rendered to the screen as desired however when the left mouse button is clicked equating to touch input on mobile devices, the scene does not switch to the second camera and the question is why?